# How To mount Directory instead of Symlink in Ubuntu

Tags: mount, fstab

I want to mount a directory to another directory. Reason to not use a symlink is Synology's stupid decision to not support it.

I have a dual boot system and work regularly on Ubuntu and Windows 10.

There is a big folder with pictures, that I don't want to have twice on my system.

Manual mounting works fine:

```
sudo mount --bind /media/windows/Users/Nabor\ Gilgalad/Pictures/mediathek /home/ngilgalad/Bilder/mediathek
```

But this entry in the /etc/fstab does not work.

```
/media/windows/Users/Nabor\ Gilgalad/Pictures/mediathek       /home/ngilgalad/Bilder/mediathek        fuse.bindfs     mirror=target   0       0
```

I think it is because of the space in the name, but how should this be done correctly?

**Update:**

It was not only the spaces in the path but also the correct type and options. That's why I also changed back the Title to the original question.

I marked the answer correct but it is indeed only a part of the solution.

This is the complete solution and works like a charm:

```
/media/windows/Users/Nabor\040Gilgalad/Pictures/mediathek      /home/ngilgalad/Bilder/mediathek        none    bind
/media/windows/Users/Nabor\040Gilgalad/Thunderbird/Mail/Local\040Folders /home/ngilgalad/Thunderbird/Mail/Local\040Folders     none    bind
```

Maybe some will find it helpful...

Comment: Use double quotes round the whole directory. But if you think it is the space: why not rename the directory?! We don't support non-official Ubuntu releases ;)

Comment: @Nabor Linux Mint is not Ubuntu. It's off topic here http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic "Questions that you should avoid: Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04), budgie-remix (16.04 & 16.10) & other Linux distributions" There are significant differences between Ubuntu and Mint. Many folks here will suggest you visit Mint Support  https://forums.linuxmint.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Double quotes doesn't Work. Renaming is not possible, because it is a Windows User directory that is named this way.

Comment: so change it in the windows end. it is a label you can change yourself. Oh and you probably need to URL encode it then so %20 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces in fstab-lines are used as delimiters for the six fields. The fstab-line will also not be interpreted by a shell, so just escaping a space in a name using a backslash will not work.

Instead, replace the space with `\040`:

```
/media/windows/Users/Nabor\040Gilgalad/Pictures/mediathek   /home/ngilgalad/Bilder/mediathek  none  bind  0  0
```

is what you need to use.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316017/how-do-i-specify-a-label-path-with-spaces-in-etc-fstab

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Filepath_spaces

Comment: That's almost correct. Besides the correct masking, the entries in the fstab have to be made a little bit different.  
`/media/windows/Users/Nabor\040Gilgalad/Thunderbird/Mail/Local\040Folders /home/ngilgalad/Thunderbird/Mail/Local\040Folders     none    bind`
Contrary to the typical "do it differently hints", it is not always possible to do it without spaces.  
As my last comment, I'd like to say that this also works with Ubuntu ;)